# pyttsx pyttsx.init() not working

Tags: python, text-to-speech, pyttsx

So I am making a Chatbot/Virtual assistant with Python, I was
searching for a text-to-speech engine for Python and found pyttsx.
I downloaded it with pip (like this: `sudo pip install pyttsx`
) (btw I am using **Linux**). I am using Python 2.7 (I tried with python 3.5 gave me the same error).
I imported it and it worked but when I put (as this tutorial "told me" to https://pythonspot.com/en/speech-engines-with-python-tutorial/) `engine = pyttsx.init()`.

The code looks like this:

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.say('Hello There')
engine.runAndWait()
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/theshoutingparrot/Desktop/Programming/Python/Bots/A.I/speechtotext.py", line 2, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyttsx/__init__.py", line 39, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyttsx/engine.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyttsx/driver.py", line 64, in __init__
    self._module = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), [driverName])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyttsx/drivers/espeak.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _espeak
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyttsx/drivers/_espeak.py", line 24, in <module>
    dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('libespeak.so.1')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 440, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be good, or suggest a nother txt-to-speech engine
Thx in advance if you can help.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install espeak 1st:

```
sudo apt-get install espeak
```

Answer (score 3):

I am working in windows 7, I got the importerror at end when doing the same & engine = pyttsx.init() wasn't working before. I installed **pypiwin32** to resolve the importerror for *win32com.client*. 
Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

I had same in Ubuntu 18.04

Install

```
sudo apt-get install espeak
```

Check it :

```
espeak --stdout "this is a test" | paplay
```

and run the following code

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init() 
engine.say("Hello There")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
import pyttsx

engine = pyttsx.init("espeak") # "espeak" defines what engine program is running on
engine.say("Hello There")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Hope this helped!