# How to solve "No package espeak available." error when trying to install speak on AWS ec2 linux?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, text-to-speech

The same code is working on my local machine(Windows) but when running the same on AWS Linux after installing Pyttsx3, it is not working.

```
    import pyttsx3
    engine = pyttsx3.init() 
    engine.say("I will speak this text")
    engine.runAndWait()
```

this is the sample code.
I am new to AWS and LINUX.

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/st_env/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/st_env/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "/home/ec2-user/st_env/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "/home/ec2-user/st_env/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ec2-user/st_env/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/espeak.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import _espeak, toUtf8, fromUtf8
  File "/home/ec2-user/st_env/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/_espeak.py", line 18, in <module>
    dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('libespeak.so.1')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 421, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 343, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

EDIT: this **OSError: libespeak.so.1:** error is there because the espeak engine is not installed on the machine(as suggested by other Stackoverflow post),
is there any way to install **espeak** than sudo yum install espeak ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyttsx pyttsx.init() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890310/pyttsx-pyttsx-init-not-working)

Comment: I tried, but still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the below commands on the amazon `ec2` instance with host os `Amazon Linux 2` and also tested your sample python code which runs successfully.

If your host system is `Amazon Linux 2` then you can install `espeak` using the below commands :

```
   __|  __|_  )
   _|  (     /   Amazon Linux 2 AMI
  ___|\___|___|

[ec2-user@aws ~]$ rpm -E %{rhel}
7                                            --> as you can see here its based on RHEL 7

[ec2-user@aws ~]$ yum list espeak
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Available Packages
espeak.i686                                                            1.47.11-4.amzn2.0.2                                                          amzn2-core
espeak.x86_64                                                          1.47.11-4.amzn2.0.2                                                          amzn2-core
```

Here you can see the `espeak` package is available on Amazon Linux.
So you need to install it using the below command :

```
ec2-user@aws ~]$ sudo yum -y install espeak
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package espeak.x86_64 0:1.47.11-4.amzn2.0.2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpulse.so.0(PULSE_0)(64bit) for package: espeak-1.47.11-4.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpulse.so.0()(64bit) for package: espeak-1.47.11-4.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package pulseaudio-libs.x86_64 0:10.0-3.amzn2.0.3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsndfile.so.1(libsndfile.so.1.0)(64bit) for package: pulseaudio-libs-10.0-3.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb.so.1()(64bit) for package: pulseaudio-libs-10.0-3.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsndfile.so.1()(64bit) for package: pulseaudio-libs-10.0-3.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libasyncns.so.0()(64bit) for package: pulseaudio-libs-10.0-3.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXtst.so.6()(64bit) for package: pulseaudio-libs-10.0-3.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libX11.so.6()(64bit) for package: pulseaudio-libs-10.0-3.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libX11-xcb.so.1()(64bit) for package: pulseaudio-libs-10.0-3.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
...
```

OR

```
yum localinstall http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/espeak-1.47.11-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

And it will install the package `espeak`.

Comment: No, when I run "sudo yum install espeak".      it says No package espeak available.

Comment: You can download the `espeak` rpm package from [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/espeak-1.47.11-4.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) and you can install it directly using `yum install FILE.rpm`

Comment: Man, there are 2 packages: Binary and Source,     which one should I go for?

Comment: use binary package. You can also run `yum search espeak` or `yum list *espeak*` to find out if it has some different name available on Amazon Linux.

Comment: If you download the source package then you first need to compile it and then install it if you are familiar with the `configure-make-make install` method.

Comment: I Downloaded the Binary and tried to install it but there are two libs/dependencies that need to be installed, and when I am installing those libs using the same method they further require some other libs. :-(

Comment: Have you tried searching for the package using `yum`? As per what I know Amazon Linux is based on CentOS and the CentOS/RHEL repo has the package `espeak`. If not try to install dependencies manually as mentioned in the [post](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/espeak-1.47.11-4.el7.x86_64.rpm.html). As your code is trying to access some Linux library `.so` file you only need to install `espeak` somehow.

Comment: I have updated my answer as you are running your code on Amazon Linux.

Comment: still NO packages available when running yum search espeak or yum list *espeak* , and when checked the version by cat /etc/os-release command it displays                                                                                  (env) [ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-224 ~]$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
 VERSION_ID="2018.03"
 PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"

Comment: can you share with me the output of `rpm -E %{rhel}`?

Comment: also, run `yum repolist` and see if this `!amzn2-core/2/x86_64 ` repo is present on your machine

Comment: @Shivampurbia, at last, you can try this `yum localinstall http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/espeak-1.47.11-4.el7.x86_64.rpm` hope this will resolve the problem.